# Rails Engine migrate_data not copying data to new translated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize

I have a Rails Engine using the Globalize Gem:

- rails (5.0.7)
- activerecord (5.0.7)
- globalize (5.1.0)

I have existing tables that I want to translate and I follow the instructions in the README:

I add the column to be translated:

```
module MyEngine
  class Website < ApplicationRecord
    translates :name
    ...
  end
end
```

and create/modify the migration (copied over to my application):

```
class CreateWebsiteTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
    reversible do |dir|

      dir.up do
        MyEngine::Website.create_translation_table!({
          :name => :string
        }, {
          :migrate_data => true
        })
      end

      dir.down do
        MyEngine::Website.drop_translation_table! :migrate_data => true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This creates a new talbe ("my_engine_website_translations") in my DB  with the name column included, however the table is empty (the name values are not being taken from the website table that is being translated:

`select * from my_engine_website_translations`

no errors: 0 rows affected

`| id | my_engine_website_id | locale | created_at | updated_at | name |`

Does anyone know what is causing this and how it can be fixed ?

Kind Regards,
Jon.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Matthieu thanks for the suggestion, however, I have now found the source of the problem:

I have a default scope within the model on the same attribute being translated, removing this while running the create_translation_table migration seems to solve the problem - values from the existing table are now being migrated correctly ...

```
translates :name
default_scope { order(name: :asc) }
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Globalize or just something I'm doing wrong, but I can work with this workaround :)

Thanks,
Jon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the [source code](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/blob/e37c471775d196cd4318e61954572c300c015467/lib/globalize/active_record/migration.rb#L136) manually after the translations table is created:

```
model = MyEngine::Website
model.find_each do |record|
  translation = record.translation_for(I18n.locale) || record.translations.build(:locale => I18n.locale)
  fields.each do |attribute_name, attribute_type|
    translation[attribute_name] = record.read_attribute(attribute_name, {:translated => false})
  end
  translation.save!
end
```

If that succeeds, it means the `migrate_data` option is indeed broken, but that seems unlikely ... Otherwise, you have a basis to debug. The only reason I see that this would not create any data is that your model has some specificity that breaks `find_each`. I see no reason why being part of an engine has any impact.

Hope this helps.